# We are peaceful, though nasty, when we are alone. Who are We?

Tags: riddle

I think it should be a really good riddle, I hope you like it.

> We are peaceful, though nasty,
>
> When we are alone.
>
> But when we get together,
>
> We start to swarm.
>
> When the swarms meet swarms,
>
> There's an outbreak of a plague.

Who are We?

Comment: This might be verging on too broad...

Comment: Is this a riddle?  A riddle would provide *indirect* clues and is often in the form of a poem.  These clues are very direct, and if it is a poem it sure doesn't have a meter or rhyme.  I wish the sandbox had worked.  The clues aren't even really correct.  In the first sentence above, how is it that the accepted answer meets to being "nasty" when they are alone?  Shouldn't the nasty refer to when they swarm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are they

> locusts

We are peaceful, though nasty,

When we are alone.

> When they are alone, they just eat leaves and live peacefully.

But when we get together,

We start to swarm.

> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locust), Locusts are certain species of short-horned grasshoppers in the family Acrididae which possess both a solitary phase and a swarming phase. These insects are usually solitary, but under certain circumstances become more abundant and change their behaviour and habits, becoming gregarious.

When the swarms meet swarms,

There's an outbreak of a plague.

> When they swarm, they damage crops and plants.

Comment: @A J right answer!!!

Comment: The plague bit might also be reference to the [Plagues of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Egypt)

Answer (score 4):

You could be:

> lice

We are peaceful, though nasty,
When we are alone.

> A louse can live alone without bothering anybody

But when we get together,
We start to swarm.

> They start to swarm on your head

When the swarms meet swarms,
There's an outbreak of a plague.

> [image: Hair with lice]
>
>   [image]

Comment: Not correct but I like your answer.

Comment: The plague bit might also be reference to the [Plagues of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagues_of_Egypt)

Answer (score 3):

> Germs

We are peaceful, though nasty,
When we are alone.

> They're not hurting anyone then

But when we get together,
We start to swarm.

> ...Yeah...

When the swarms meet swarms,
There's an outbreak of a plague.

> They *are* plagues.

Comment: @Mithradir not correct!!

Comment: This kinda does fit the riddle though

Comment: @BlueFire That's what makes this a *bad riddle* - it is too broad, and see the comment on the main post.